# PHP fsockopen giving error with SSL

Tags: php, ssl, smtp, ubuntu-18.04

I am getting the error while connecting to fsockopen.

```
echo $result = fsockopen('ssl://smtp.gmail.com', 465, $error_no, $error_message, 5);
//$result = fsockopen('tls://smtp.gmail.com', 587, $error_no, $error_message, 5);
if ($result === false) {
  echo "error no: $error_no error message: $error_message";
  echo print_r($result, true);
} else {
  echo 'success';
}
```

> error no: 0 error message:

I checked the manual [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) which says

> If the value returned in errno is 0 and the function returned
> false, it is an indication that the error occurred before the
> connect() call. This is most likely due to a problem initializing the
> socket.

But I do not know how to resolve this. I have an AWS Ubuntu 18.04 instance and the website is https.

The problem is I am trying to set up gmail smtp. This settings works fine on local as well as other AWS instances where SSL isn't installed

**UPDATE 1**:

```
print_r(stream_get_transports());
```

The above statement gives

```
Array (
    [0] => tcp
    [1] => udp
    [2] => unix
    [3] => udg
    [4] => ssl
    [5] => tls
    [6] => tlsv1.0
    [7] => tlsv1.1
    [8] => tlsv1.2 
)
```

Comment: Do you have a way to check if the connection is working without PHP ? Like with "openssl" command ? Are you sure that the PHP have the ssl support enabled ? print_r(stream_get_transports());

Comment: @Dom, Yes. Please check the update.

Comment: try enabling error_reporting(E_ALL) or check the error_log  - it could be some DNS issue. Additionally as suggested try "openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465" in a console to see if a connection can be established from your server

Comment: This appears to be off-topic here. Programming questions should be asked on [so].

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I edited the question also

Answer (score 1):

You don't receive an error, as you can see: $error_no is zero.

Your command

```
echo $result = fsockopen(...)
```

makes no sense, or certainly not what you want.  You echo the contents of the result variable, followed by an equals sign, followed by - if fsockopen is really executed - the file variable returned by fsockopen.  See [PHP manual fsockopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) for the correct usage.

Comment: Programming questions should be answered on [so].

Comment: @MichaelHampton, It is not a programming question. This is something related to SSL that I clearly mentioned in the question description.

Comment: Maybe the question isn't, but the problem is clearly a programming one.